# User created database or table

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I need to create a database where a user enters a first and last name and then that gets recorded into a table that can be sorted alphabetically.

I have what I think is the makings of a PHP table here:

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql6.000webhost.com","owen","*********","student");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE Persons (PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(PID), FirstName CHAR(15), LastName CHAR(15))";

// Execute query
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  echo "Table persons created successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
  }
?>
```

Next I have the actual html code where the user submits his or her name:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-W6qoXhCjKSs/Tpul-XAR3-I/AAAAAAAACeU/Oe1ZEzpnUCg/s1600/sbstweb.gif">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
        <title>Almost Done!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img class= "logo" src= "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-W6qoXhCjKSs/Tpul-XAR3-I/AAAAAAAACeU/Oe1ZEzpnUCg/s1600/sbstweb.gif">
        <h1>Enter your name below to complete the quiz</h1>  
        <form action="insert.php" method="post">
            <p><input autofocus name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" type="text"></p>
            <p><input autofocus name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text"></p>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And lastly I have what I think is PHP code that inserts the new entries into the database:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql6.000webhost.com","a3159217_owen","*********","a3159217_student");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My first question is how to get the PHP code to implement and work. When I hit submit in the webpage, it directs me to the insert.php code that I made. How do I get it to submit to the database, and how do I create the database in the first place.

Second, to actually show the table, do I have to make another html page that renders the PHP table? How does this work?

Comment: 1. put it in a file, on a web server that runs php. you should not be writing that much code with out the ability to run it.

Comment: So I tried that, and it says that MySQL access is denied. It says that I am using password YES, but I am not and YES is nowhere in my code. Where should the password be put in the MySQL connect prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this will help or not. 
But for MYSQL, in order to connect a database, the code is as below.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
```

for mysqli,

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
```

you may refered to http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php.

Comment: I tried this, and it sucessfully connected, however it is giving me 2 errors. Connected successfully
PHP Error Message

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in /home/a3159217/public_html/database/insert.php on line 13

Free Web Hosting

PHP Error Message

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in /home/a3159217/public_html/database/insert.php on line 15

Free Web Hosting
Error:

Comment: alright you cant really decipher that so here is a screeshot of it: http://i.imgur.com/F3s9s9U.png

Comment: can u try like this '$result = mysqli_query ($con, $sql) or trigger_error("Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con));"

Comment: where do you want this section of code? when i put it at the end after the insert function it gives me the same thing as above.

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]')"; and replace the if-else loop with the code...if the problem still existed, u need to check ur mysqli_connect

Comment: student is your table name or database name?

Comment: from your screenshot, the bottom show the message 'Error : [blank]"... this line should be generate from "die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));" maybe something was wrong on your $con.

Comment: student is my database name. persons is my table name

Comment: Okay thanks, that actually fixed the problem. I think I can figure the rest out on my own. thanks for your help